# How to 301 redirect all pages to the same pages on new domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm moving my site from old-domain.com to new-domain.com with exactly the same pages, e.g., if old-domain.com has a page1.html (i.e., old-domain.com/page1.html) then the new domain has the same page, i.e., new-domain.com/page1.html

I tried this in the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But only while old-domain.com will redirect to new-domain.com, old-domain.com/page1.html **will not** redirect to new-domain.com/page1.html

Thanks!

Comment: (.*) won't match the HOST, only the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 18):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !newdomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

See here for more solutions: http://enarion.net/web/htaccess/migrate-domains/

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.new.com/
```

This will redirect (and map) all your pages from http://old.com/page1 to http://new.com/page1

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't work on my site. Also no luck from other developers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15167630/301-redirect-everything-to-new-website-root-whole-site-including-sub-pages-move#comment21433867_15167630

Comment: You might need to add RewriteEngine On & RewriteBase / first

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://www.new-domain.com/
```