# 301 Redirect all pages to same page on new domain

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is a follow-up question to [.htaccess redirect all pages to new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945568/htaccess-redirect-all-pages-to-new-domain) and [How to 301 redirect all pages to the same pages on new domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643271/how-to-301-redirect-all-pages-to-the-same-pages-on-new-domain).

Specifically, how are the following solutions different?

`RewriteRule` Solution:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

`Redirect` Solution:

```
Redirect 301 / http://newdomain.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a server redirect vs. a browser redirect. In the first case internal redirect will be made and a browser will receive a response from the target server.

In the second case a browser will be served with a 301 code (moved permanently) and a Location header with a new URL, at which point it'll need to make a second request to the target server.

You can see the difference yourself, e.g. by installing "Live HTTP Headers" plugin in Firefox and checking all requests that your browser receives.

Comment: + I assume the *rewrite* solution is more performant considering the extra round trip of the *redirect* solution.

Comment: Correct, but there are security considerations. I think, in general explicit browser redirects are more secure